# Kinect JS cropping rectangle

Tags: html, image, canvas, crop, jcrop

I am already using `jQuery` plugin called j`Crop` but recently I discovered `KinectJs` and it really solves many problems for me. Then I stumbled upon this example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/

And I decided to write my own cropping rectangle based on `KinectJs` and above example.

```
    function update(activeAnchor) {
var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
var cropper = group.get('.cropper')[0];

var leftMask = group.getParent().get('.leftMask')[0];
var rightMask = group.getParent().get('.rightMask')[0];
var topMask = group.getParent().get('.topMask')[0];
var bottomMask = group.getParent().get('.bottomMask')[0];

var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

// update anchor positions
switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
    case 'topLeft':
        topRight.setY(anchorY);
        bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
        updateLeftMaskWidth(leftMask,activeAnchor);
        updateTopMaskHeight(topMask,cropper,activeAnchor);
        break;
    case 'topRight':
        topLeft.setY(anchorY);
        bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
        updateRightMaskWidthAndPos(rightMask,activeAnchor);
        updateTopMaskHeight(topMask,cropper,activeAnchor);
        break;
    case 'bottomRight':
        bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
        topRight.setX(anchorX);
        updateRightMaskWidthAndPos(rightMask,activeAnchor);
        updateBottomMaskHeightAndPos(bottomMask,cropper,activeAnchor);
        break;
    case 'bottomLeft':
        bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
        topLeft.setX(anchorX);
        updateLeftMaskWidth(leftMask,activeAnchor);
        updateBottomMaskHeightAndPos(bottomMask,cropper,activeAnchor);
        break;
    }

    cropper.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition().x,topLeft.getPosition().y);

    var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
    var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
    if(width && height) {
        cropper.setSize(width, height);
    }
}

function updateLeftMaskWidth(mask,leftAnchor) {
    mask.setWidth(leftAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().x - 100);
}

function updateRightMaskWidthAndPos(mask,rightAnchor) {
    mask.setAbsolutePosition(rightAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().x,mask.getAbsolutePosition().y);
    mask.setWidth(213 - (rightAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().x - 100));
}

function updateTopMaskHeight(mask,cropper,topAnchor) {
    mask.setAbsolutePosition(topAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().x,mask.getAbsolutePosition().y);
    mask.setHeight(topAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().y - 110);
    mask.setWidth(cropper.getWidth());
}

function updateBottomMaskHeightAndPos(mask,cropper,bottomAnchor) {
    mask.setAbsolutePosition(bottomAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().x, bottomAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().y);
    mask.setHeight(236 - (bottomAnchor.getAbsolutePosition().y - 110));
    mask.setWidth(cropper.getWidth());
}

function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
var stage = group.getStage();
var layer = group.getLayer();

var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    stroke: '#666',
    fill: '#ddd',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    radius: 5,
    name: name,
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        var newX = pos.x;
        var newY = pos.y;
        var image = this.getParent().getParent().get('.image')[0];
        var cropper = this.getParent();

        // Bound horizontally
        if(newX < 100) {
            newX = 100;
        }
        else if(newX > image.getWidth() + 100 - cropper.getWidth()) {
            newX = image.getWidth() + 100 - cropper.getWidth();
        }

        if(newY < 110) {
            newY = 110;
        }
        else if(newY > image.getHeight() + 110 - cropper.getHeight()) {
            newY = image.getHeight() + 110 - cropper.getHeight();
        }

        return {
            x: newX,
            y: newY
        }
    }
});

anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
    update(this);
    layer.draw();
});
// add hover styling
anchor.on('mouseover', function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    this.setStrokeWidth(2);
    layer.draw();
});
anchor.on('mouseout', function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    this.setStrokeWidth(2);
    layer.draw();
});

group.add(anchor);
}

function initStage(img) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 578,
        height: 400
    });
    var imageGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
        x: 100,
        y: 110
    });
var leftMaskGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 100,
    y: 110
});

var rightMaskGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 270,
    y: 110
});

var topMaskGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 169.9,
    y: 110
});

var bottomMaskGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 169.9,
    y: 150+138
});

var cropperGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
    x: 170,
    y: 150,
    draggable: true,
    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
        var newX = pos.x;
        var newY = pos.y;
        var image = this.getParent().get('.image')[0];
        var cropper = this.get('.cropper')[0];

        // Bound horizontally
        if(newX < 100) {
            newX = 100;
        }
        else if(newX > image.getWidth() + 100 - cropper.getWidth()) {
            newX = image.getWidth() + 100 - cropper.getWidth();
        }

        // Bound vertically
        if(newY < 110) {
            newY = 110;
        }
        else if(newY > image.getHeight() + 110 - cropper.getHeight()) {
            newY = image.getHeight() + 110 - cropper.getHeight();
        }

        return {
            x: newX,
            y: newY
        }
    }
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

/*
 * go ahead and add the groups
 * to the layer and the layer to the
 * stage so that the groups have knowledge
 * of its layer and stage
 */

layer.add(imageGroup);
layer.add(leftMaskGroup);
layer.add(rightMaskGroup);
layer.add(topMaskGroup);
layer.add(bottomMaskGroup);
layer.add(cropperGroup);
stage.add(layer);

// cropping rectangle
var cropperRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100,
    height: 138,
    stroke: 'black',
    name: 'cropper',
    strokeWidth: 1
});

cropperGroup.add(cropperRect);
addAnchor(cropperGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft');
addAnchor(cropperGroup, 100, 0, 'topRight');
addAnchor(cropperGroup, 100, 138, 'bottomRight');
addAnchor(cropperGroup, 0, 138, 'bottomLeft');

cropperGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
    this.moveToTop();
});

cropperGroup.on('dragmove', function() {
    var layer = this.getLayer();
    var topLeft = this.get('.topLeft')[0];
    var bottomLeft = this.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
    var topRight = this.get('.topRight')[0];
    var leftMask = this.getParent().get('.leftMask')[0];
    var rightMask = this.getParent().get('.rightMask')[0];
    var topMask = this.getParent().get('.topMask')[0];
    var bottomMask = this.getParent().get('.bottomMask')[0];
    updateLeftMaskWidth(leftMask,topLeft);
    updateRightMaskWidthAndPos(rightMask,topRight);
    updateTopMaskHeight(topMask,this.get('.cropper')[0],topLeft);
    updateBottomMaskHeightAndPos(bottomMask,this.get('.cropper')[0],bottomLeft);
    layer.draw();
});

// left mask
var leftMaskRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 70,
    height: 236,
    fill: 'black',
    name: 'leftMask',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    opacity: 0.5
});

leftMaskGroup.add(leftMaskRect);

// right mask
var rightMaskRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 213-170,
    height: 236,
    fill: 'black',
    name: 'rightMask',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    opacity: 0.5
});

rightMaskGroup.add(rightMaskRect);

// top mask
var topMaskRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100.2,
    height: 150-110,
    fill: 'black',
    name: 'topMask',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    opacity: 0.5
});

topMaskGroup.add(topMaskRect);

// bottom mask
var bottomMaskRect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 100.2,
    height: 236-138-(150-110),
    fill: 'black',
    name: 'bottomMask',
    strokeWidth: 0,
    opacity: 0.5
});

bottomMaskGroup.add(bottomMaskRect);

// image
var srcImg = new Kinetic.Image({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    image: img,
    name: 'image'
});

imageGroup.add(srcImg);

stage.draw();
}
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    initStage(this);
}
img.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg';
```

It works almost perfectly. The problem is that when you resize using the circle anchors and after a few tries (just give it a few shots) when you try to drag the whole rectangle it allows you to drag it out of bounds !

[image: Illustration of the problem]

From my debugging this seems like an issue with the library but if sb. sees the problem in my code or sees a way to optimize it please share your thoughts.

The result of my effort can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wanderer/WLpXF/

Comment: Is this browser specific !? or with Chrome/Firefox this will do!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) Reproducing the bug:

1. Drag a top anchor *upwards* (say it was dragged N pixels)
2. Drag the entire cropper *upwards*; it can leave the image boundaries by N pixels

Similar behaviour for the other anchors and directions.

B) The solution:

Add this function to the script:

```
function readjust() {
    var group = this.getParent();

    var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
    var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
    var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
    var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
    var cropper = group.get('.cropper')[0];

    var tlx = cropper.getX(),
        tly = cropper.getY(),
        w = cropper.getWidth(),
        h = cropper.getHeight();

    group.setX(group.getX() + tlx);
    group.setY(group.getY() + tly);

    topLeft.setPosition(0,0);
    topRight.setPosition(w,0);
    bottomLeft.setPosition(0,h);
    bottomRight.setPosition(w,h);
    cropper.setPosition(0,0);
}
```

And the following handler in `addAnchor()`:

```
anchor.on('dragend', readjust);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BMy7b/1/

Alternatively the code from `readjust()` can be included in `update()`, as suggested by MarmiK. This would run more operations on every drag thus *might* be slower (but I am not sure; opinions?). Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vUPeQ/1/

The problem was that the cropper and anchors moved relatively to the `cropperGroup`, but the `cropperGroup` drag bounding function wasn't taking it into account.

Have fun!

Comment: I think this should also go with this anchor.on('dragmove', function() {
        update(this);
        layer.draw();
    });

Comment: I guess the logic of `update()` and `readjust()` could be merged. However, the change as suggested is minimally invasive to the original code.

Comment: I was just doing same thing that you did so we just need to add your function in the 'dragmove' part of the original function, the dragging  is also one of the cause which changes the canvas too some how.

Comment: Indeed, adding the stuff of `readjust()` after `var tlx=...` to the bottom of `update()` and removing all other changes accomplishes the same thing. I think the dragging is a little slower though (more operations per drag probably?).

Comment: You might want to prevent the case where the focus rectangle becomes inverted (eg., top drag circles can be dragged below the bottom drag circles) When this case happens, the focus rectangle can still be dragged outside the image.

Answer (score 1):

One quick update: I was after something like this (nice looking cropping rectangle), but when I try this code with the latest KineticJS 5.0.1, well, it does a couple of nasty things. You can see by yourselves here: [http://jsfiddle.net/vUPeQ/2/]:http://jsfiddle.net/vUPeQ/2/

My wild guess is that it's because some api changes, but I can't find which one...

Can anyone give a hand over here?

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Yes the API changed. To make it work you have to acknowledge that from version 5.0.0 `all multi-dimensional inputs and outputs must be object literals for performance reasons. i.e. shape.setScale(1) will no longer work. You need to use shape.setScale({x: 1, y: 1});`. For our example this implies that you have to change all `setPosition(xCoord,yCoord)` and `setAbsolutePosition(xCoord,yCoord)` to `setPosition({x:xCoord,y:yCoord})` and `setAbsolutePosition({x:xCoord,y:yCoord})`.Last to change is `setSize(newWidth,newHeight)' which must be changed to `setSize({width:newWidth,height:newHeight})`.